# HDMI1 is disconnected

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm trying to get a secondary monitor working with my laptop. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have Windows 10 installed on the same laptop and it works in Windows 10. Currently `xrandr -q` outputs:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1600 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1600x900      60.08*+
   1440x900      59.89  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I don't see anything that stands out in dmesg and /var/log/Xorg.0.log doesn't log anything when I plug in the HDMI chord.

According to `lspci -v` I have this for my graphics card:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
        Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

I installed xserver-xorg-video-intel and libdrm-intel1.

I've also tried

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

And then on the last command I get `xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed`.

`xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto` doesn't do anything.

Anyone recommend anything or trying anything? When I plug in the HDMI chord the monitor's power light turns blue, then a few seconds later it says "No signal detected." So it at least knows it's plugged in, but like the laptop is not listening there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved, I just had to run this:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --right-of eDP1
```

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem on my Dell G3, running Kubuntu 20.04 with a NVidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti.

```
xrandr -q
```

showed "HDMI-1 disconnected"

What I had to do was uninstall all nvidia drivers, using:

```
sudo apt remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
```

Then, after restarting, I installed the latest nvidia driver, which at the time was:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
```

Then everything went back to normal. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It saved my time!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing almost the same problem. I suggest you to remove your nvidia drivers in case of having nvidia drivers and reinstall the latest version and once booting again enter you secure password (that you set while installing the new nvidia drivers) while booting (Mok) and that's solved my issue