# Secondary display not detected

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I linked up a secondary display via HDMI but I'm not getting a signal. xrandr output is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    40.02  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I already tried changing to lightdm and selecting a different set of drivers but to no avail. Anyone got any ideas on how to fix this? Pretty new to Linux so let me know if any additional info is required.

Comment: Found this: "https://askubuntu.com/questions/796827/hdmi1-is-disconnected" thread. Solution there didn't work. ~$ xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --right-of eDP1
warning: output HDMI1 not found; ignoring

Comment: Does following this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284567/cannot-connect-second-monitor-via-hdmi-cable-in-ubuntu-20-04

Answer (score 0):

This command lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use' told me what driver I was using --namely -- from the kernel
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel driver in use: radeon
so then I ran the command uname -a
and got that I was using the 5.4.0-48-generic
so I went to https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.4/+bugs
and found out there are some bugs
Not sure of the solution yet, thinking I should role back to previous kernel

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Please let me know if you found a solution.